# Прелоадер Flash игры JS

Tags: javascript, flash

Как через JS определить, что Flash файл был полностью загружен и готов к использованию ?

Comment: Он ещё не вымер?

Comment: Говорят в 2020 должен умереть, но еще используется =_=

Comment: Подписаться на onload не катит?

Comment: Ещё можно из флеша дёрнуть какой-то глобальный коллбэк.

Comment: @Qwertiy onload увы не работает. Пробовал ставить wmode="transparent", но производительность падает на столько сильно, что пришлось отказаться

Comment: Никогда не использовал flash. И гугл совершенно не отвечает, какая вообще связь между wmode и загрузкой.

Comment: @Qwertiy связь в том, что пока Flash объект не начал загружаться, видно прелоадер, как начинает загружаться - появляется фон (и тогда прелоадер больше не видно) или прелоадер все еще видно (при wmode transparent), а как только загрузится - уже видно само приложение (при transparent жуткие лаги)

Comment: @ZaArs советую забыть Flash, т.к. его скоро перестанут поддерживать.

Comment: Если бы я мог  забыл, то  забыл, а пока есть задача - приходится как то решать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще оказалось таки написать на ActionScript3 флеш прелоадер и из него вызывать функцию. Осталось только проблема, что объект не кешируется